# The type or namespace EventProcessorClient could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am starting off with Event Hubs with .Net Core and am facing a very peculiar issue when trying to write the same code as in the official MS documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-dotnet-standard-send-v2). The event receiver code throws an error although I'm using it's containing namespace i.e. Azure.Messaging.EventHubs. Where am I going wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have imported the correct Nuget package as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install  [`Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor/5.0.0-preview.6) as a dependency to the project. Even though the answer above is correct, I just attached the link.